# Prevent users from putting dots in front of their nicknames on Discord (discord.js / Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to write a script that would detect if and when a user changes their name on discord to something like ".bob" from "bob", it'll disallow this change and keep it as "bob".

```
if (user.nickname.startsWith(".")) {
    user.nickname = "bob";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is something that Discord bots can do?

Comment: I don't think this is possible... What about setting a time for every 30 minutes or an hour, checking user nicknames, and changing them if they have "." in front?

Comment: yes! even that would work, I'm just attempting to figure out how an if statement would look for that, the check could even be every hour or so, doesn't matter, I just don't want people to have dots in front of their names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [guildMemberUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event to check when a member changes their nickname and then you can check `if` the new nickname [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) a `'.'`, here's an example of how that would look:

I prefer using [`displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) rather than `nickname` as if the member doesn't have a nickname their `nickname` will return `null`

```
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {  // this event triggers when a member changes their nickname.
    if (newMember.displayName.startsWith('.')) { // checks if the new nickname starts with a .
        newMember.setNickname(oldMember.displayName) //changes the member's nickname back to their old nickname
            .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

Also, keep in mind that this will only work if the member's [`highestRole`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=highestRole) 's [`position`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=position) is less than the bot's highestRole position, so you may want to check that first of handle that in your `.catch()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to replace all "." in the staring

```
user.nickname = user.nickname.replace(/\./g,'');
```

Codepen for reference: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/papGzK

Comment: No, but I'm also looking here to see how I can actually get the discord bot to even detect when the user has changed their name, I haven't seen anywhere in discords docs how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js has an event listener called guildMemberUpdate. This event listener is executed when a user has updated their nickname, so you can use this event listener to your advantage. For example,

```
Client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (past, current) => {
    if (current.displayName.startsWith(".")) {
        current.setNickname(past.displayName);
    }
});
```

Note: In order for this code to work, your bot must have `MANAGE_NICKNAMES` permissions.
Hope this was helpful.